# Company mode (Emacs plugin) back-end could not be initialized?

Tags: plugins, emacs

Every time I initiate company-mode with `M-x company-mode` this message shows up:

```
Company back-end 'company-semantic' could not be initialized
Company back-end 'company-ropemacs' could not be initialized
Company back-end 'company-pysmell' could not be initialized
```

The completion works but I wonder whats the meaning of that message and how to fix it.

**EDIT:** I moved company-semantic.el company-ropemacs.el company-pysmell.el to ~.emacs.d\plugins\company-0.4.3\unused-backends but I'm still getting that error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

semantic, ropemacs and pysmell are all emacs extensions. Do you have them installed?

If you don't intend to use them, a quick workaround would be to remove or move that files that define those back-ends, which would prevent company mode from trying to load them.

`cd /location/of/company
mkdir unused-backends
mv company-semantic.* company-ropemacs.* company-pysmell.* unused-backends/`

As long as you do not add unused-backends to your load-path, this will fix the problem.

If you want to use those backends (semantic is a parser for better context-appropriate emacs actions based on language, pysmell and ropemacs are both for usage with python), then installing them should fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I had to install them separately.

Comment: This is exactly the wrong way to go about it. The right way is customize `company-backends` (like the second answer recommends), or file a bug report for company-mode.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of changing your company-mode install directory. Just define company-backends in your .emacs file. E.g.

```
(setq company-backends '(company-elisp 
                         company-ropemacs
                         company-gtags
                         company-dabbrev-code
                         company-keywords
                         company-files 
                         company-dabbrev))
```

Excluding the backends you do not want to support from the list.